# Consecutive numbers removed by a sieve

Tags: number-theory, sieve-theory

This is a question about a particular sieve, which interests me because it has implications for twin primes. Consider primes of the form $p_i=6k_i \pm 1$. In a sequential manner, starting with $p_1=5$, for each such prime, mark for removal natural numbers $a \equiv \pm k_i \bmod p_i$. **My question is:** After each round of this sieving procedure, what is the length of the longest stretch of consecutive numbers that have been marked for removal? If a specific value for that length cannot be formulated, can some upper bound be placed on it?

I do not know of a conceptual basis for attacking this problem, but I am hoping some member of the community might. By brute force, I have analyzed the first three rounds. In analyzing round $i$, it is only necessary to analyze stretches among numbers up to $a \le q=\prod p_i$, as any pattern in that range repeats for larger numbers $b=a+nq$.

After round 2 (up to $5 \times 7=35$), the longest such stretch is $4$, which occurs twice beginning at $13$ and $19$. After round 3 (up to $5 \times 7 \times 11=385$), the longest stretch is $6$, which occurs four times beginning at $151,159,221,229$. Unsurprisingly, a stretch that begins at some value $x$ is reflected in a similar stretch that ends at $q-x$. Analyzing the residue classes of $5005$ members of round 4 is beyond my capacity to work by hand.

For each new round involving $p_i$, the numbers marked for removal will be spaced apart alternately by $2k_i$ and $p_i-2k_i \approx 4k_i$. In  view of this, the expectation is that any particular stretch from earlier rounds may be lengthened by at most $2$, or two such stretches may be fused if they are separated by no more than one unmarked number.

Comment: What is the intuition for removing $a\equiv k_i\bmod{p_i}$?

Comment: @Don Thousand I did not want to include a lengthy digression proving the point in this post, but it is demonstrable that if $6m \pm 1$ is a pair of twin primes, then $\forall k < m,\ m \not \equiv \pm k \bmod (6k \pm 1)$

Comment: Ah, I forgot this was about twin primes. Got it.

Comment: [no connection with this question]@Bernard Thanks for the reference. Good to share humor by these times.

Comment: I looked into this a few months ago, while trying to find an answer to my own question (which I see listed here as related). The assumptions in your last paragraph seem reasonable, but it rapidly gets more complicated than that unfortunately: "multi-mergers" are in fact possible, and I can't see a way to predict when they happen and/or how they behave. (example follows)

Comment: $$\begin{array}{ll}
118 &-1 \pmod{7} \\
119 &-1 \pmod{5} \\
120 &+1 \pmod{7} \\
121 &+1 \pmod{5} \\
\mathbf{122} &\mathbf{+3 \pmod{17}} \\
123 &+2 \pmod{11} \\
124 &-1 \pmod{5} \\
125 &-1 \pmod{7} \\
126 &+1 \pmod{5} \\
127 &+1 \pmod{7} \\
128 &-2 \pmod{13} \\
129 &-1 \pmod{5} \\
130 &-2 \pmod{11} \\
131 &+1 \pmod{5} \\
132 &-1 \pmod{7} \\
\mathbf{133} &\mathbf{-3 \pmod{17}} \\
134 &-1 \pmod{5} \\
\end{array}$$
A "double-merge" happening for $\bmod{17}$. It seems clear to me that "mergers" with more segments cannot be ruled out, and this makes the behavior hard to track...